# AlertDialog style for MultiChoiceItems

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Hi I'm desperately trying to style the MultiChoiceItems of my DialogFragment. For some reason I can only change the color of the title, the positive/negative/neutral buttons and the checkboxes; but! not the corresponding item names - they keep staying black. I would like to change the item names to a brighter whitish color ..

This is the style I use so far:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#444</item>


    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>


</style>
```

[image: My AlertDialogFragment]

**EDIT**: I'm using API 21 !

Answer (score 0):

after trying almost every possible combination LOL I found out that by adding this attribute:

```
<item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/white</item>
```

The item names changed its color into white!!